# Property Set not fire when deserialize(xml) a list of

Tags: vb.net, serialization, xml-serialization, getter-setter

I got a class containing integer,bool,string and list (of integer). Each variable that need to be serialize in that class has a public property. When i deserialize my class via *XmlSerializer* the public property of each variable is call. Except the variable that are *list of*. The List of varaibles are weel deserialisze but the property setter isn't called.

Here is the property :

```
Public Property Ana_Offset As List(Of Integer)
    Get
        Return _Ana_Offset
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of Integer))
        Tmp_Val = _Ana_Offset
        _Ana_Offset = value

        RaiseEvent VariableChanged(_Ana_Offset, Tmp_Val, "_Ana_Offset", 0)
    End Set
End Property
```

The class is something like this

```
<Serializable()> Public Class SACCVar

    Private _Code_Produit As String
    Private _Ana_Offset As New List(Of Integer)

    Public Event VariableChanged(ByVal Val As Object, ByVal Old_Val As Object, desc As String, index As Integer)

    End Class
```

The strange fact i just realise while posting is that i got no Set "event" but the get event is fired wit no data return, but for other variable the get isn't fired..?

Thanks for help

Comment: Since `Ana_Offset ` is a List, serializers can simply `Add` to it.  They need not create a list and assign it.  Which may expose a flaw: your code can change list elements as well with no event firing

Comment: Ok and do you have a way to get an event on the `add` method?

Comment: Why do you want the event to fire when deserializing?  Cant you run a method afterwards to process the whole list since the whole list changed as a result?  Usually, you want to suppress those events when de/serializing.  It doesnt help the other part - your code could change the list directly too

Comment: When deserializing a writable collection (like `List<T>`), `XmlSerializer` will use the pre-existing collection if one exists and not set it back.  If it needs to allocate the collection, it will do so and then set it back immediately, *before populating it*.  (This allows for serialization of [read-only collection properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx).)  You will need to use an observable collection or proxy array property as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927496/xml-deserialization-of-collection-property-with-code-defaults

Comment: Thanks all. @plutonix i started writing the method but i was searching a way not to do that as all the code was ever written...