# C# XML Serialization in UWP

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying serialize more than one list to a unique xml file. 
My project is a UWP, currrently it seems serialize my 3 list but the file is showed empty.
Previously a user help me with part of the code.
How I could correctly serialize it.

> To execute my code only use: "project();"

All my code:

```
using Project.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Windows.Storage;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project
{
    public class All_Classes
    {
        public class List1 : BindableBase
        {
            private int _Property1;
            public int Property1
            {
                get { return _Property1; }
                set { SetProperty(ref _Property1, value); }
            }

            private bool _Property2;
            public bool Property2
            {
                get { return _Property2; }
                set { SetProperty(ref _Property2, value); }
            }

            private bool _Property3;
            public bool Property3
            {
                get { return _Property3; }
                set { SetProperty(ref _Property3, value); }
            }
        }

        public class List2 : BindableBase
        {

            private bool _Property1;
            public bool Property1
            {
                get { return _Property1; }
                set { SetProperty(ref _Property1, value); }
            }

            private bool _Property2;
            public bool Property2
            {
                get { return _Property2; }
                set { SetProperty(ref _Property2, value); }
            }
        }

        public class List3 : BindableBase
        {
            private double _Property1;
            public double Property1
            {
                get { return _Property1; }
                set { SetProperty(ref _Property1, value); }
            }

            private double _Property2;
            public double Property2
            {
                get { return _Property2; }
                set { SetProperty(ref _Property2, value); }
            }

            private double _Property3;
            public double Property3
            {
                get { return _Property3; }
                set { SetProperty(ref _Property3, value); }
            }

            private double _Property4;
            public double Property4
            {
                get { return _Property4; }
                set { SetProperty(ref _Property4, value); }
            }

        }

        public class Values_List1 : ObservableCollection<List1>
        {
        }
        public class Values_List2 : ObservableCollection<List2>
        {
        }
        public class Values_List3 : ObservableCollection<List3>
        {
        }

        public static class ApplicationServices
        {
            public static Values_List1 List1 = new Values_List1();
            public static Values_List2 List2 = new Values_List2();
            public static Values_List3 List3 = new Values_List3();

            static ApplicationServices()
            {
            }
        }

        public static void AddNewData()
        {
            ApplicationServices.List1.Add(new List1()
            {
                Property1 = 1,
                Property2 = true,
                Property3 = false,

            });

            ApplicationServices.List2.Add(new List2()
            {
                Property1 = false,
                Property2 = true,
            });

            ApplicationServices.List3.Add(new List3()
            {
                Property1 = 3.564,
                Property2 = 0.215,
                Property3 = 0.7252,
                Property4 = 23.463,
            });
        }

        public static async void SaveObjectToXml<T>(T objectToSave)
        {
            //<-----------FilePicker------------------>
            var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
            savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
            savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("New File", new List<string>() { ".xml" });
            savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New File";
            StorageFile newfile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
            //<-----------FilePicker------------------>
            //<----------------Serializacion------------------>

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            Stream stream = await newfile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();


            using (stream)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, objectToSave);
            }
            //<----------------Serializacion------------------>

        }

        public class myCompoundClass
        {
            public List1 List1 { get; set; }
            public List2 List2 { get; set; }
            public List3 List3 { get; set; }
        }

        public static void project()
        {
            myCompoundClass new_instance = new myCompoundClass();
            AddNewData();
            SaveObjectToXml(new_instance);
        }

    }
}
```

> I wanna get something similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <List1>
    <Property1>1</Property1>
    <Property2>true</Property2>
    <Property3>false</Property3>
    <ToAcero>0.1</ToAcero>
  </List1>
  <List2>
    <Property1>true</Property1>
    <Property2>true</Property2>
  </List2>
  <List3>
    <Property1>3.564</Property1>
    <Property2>0.215</Property2>
    <Property3>0.7252</Property3>
    <Property4>23.463</Property4>
  </List3>
</Root>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set any of the property values `List1` or `List2` or `List3` inside your `myCompoundClass`:

```
        myCompoundClass new_instance = new myCompoundClass();
        AddNewData();
        // new_instance was not passed to AddNewData and so its properties have their default values of null.
        SaveObjectToXml(new_instance);
```

Thus all its properties will still be `null`.  That's why your XML file is empty.  You need to move your data from your `static class ApplicationServices` into the `new_instance` before serializing.

**Update**

You ask, *how I can fill "new_instance" with ApplicationServices?*  Your problem is that you would like to serialize your `ApplicationServices` class but it is a static class and so cannot be serialized as-is.  My suggestions would be:

1. Rename your types.  You have types such as `List1` that are *not lists*.  I'd suggest something like the following:

   ```
   public class Values1 : BindableBase // Formerly List1
   {
       // Contents unchanged
   }

   public class Values2 : BindableBase // Formerly List2
   {
       // Contents unchanged
   }

   public class Values3 : BindableBase // Formerly List3
   {
       // Contents unchanged
   }

   public class Values1List : ObservableCollection<Values1>
   {
   }
   public class Values2List : ObservableCollection<Values2>
   {
   }
   public class Values3List : ObservableCollection<Values3>
   {
   }
   ```

   Your existing naming conventions are misleading as to what is and is not a collection.

   Also, I suggest that you do not nest them inside the `All_Classes` class.  Doing so adds complexity rather than clarity.
2. Make the static value lists be read-only:

   ```
   public static class ApplicationServices
   {
       public static readonly Values1List List1 = new Values1List();
       public static readonly Values2List List2 = new Values2List();
       public static readonly Values3List List3 = new Values3List();

       static ApplicationServices()
       {
       }
   }
   ```
3. Since you cannot serialize a static type, introduce the following data transfer object for serialization:

   ```
   [XmlRoot("Root")]
   public class ApplicationServicesDTO
   {
       [XmlElement]
       public Values1List List1 { get { return ApplicationServices.List1; } }

       [XmlElement]
       public Values2List List2 { get { return ApplicationServices.List2; } }

       [XmlElement]
       public Values3List List3 { get { return ApplicationServices.List3; } }
   }
   ```

   Some notes:

   - Note that the `List` properties are get-only.  In general `XmlSerializer` will not serialize get-only properties, but it will serialize get-only *collection properties* when the collection is preallocated.
   - [`[XmlRoot("Root")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx) indicates that the type should be serialized with a root element named `<Root>`.
   - [`[XmlElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) applied to a collection property indicates that the collection should be serialized as a repeated sequence of elements without an outer container element.

Now you will be able to do:

```
var new_instance = new ApplicationServicesDTO();
```

And you static lists will get serialized with the XML format you want.

Note that if you later want to deserialize your XML, you may want to clear the pre-existing lists inside `ApplicationServices` first. For an explanation see [XML Deserialization of collection property with code defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927496/xml-deserialization-of-collection-property-with-code-defaults).

Comment: What a fail, your right sir, but I need add my data to ApplicationServices but it is static then I cant instance it, how I can fill "new_instance"  with ApplicationServices, can you help me?