# C# - Deserializing XML - XmlText gets Null instead of string itself

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, serialization

I'm trying to parse an XML message from a string.
The string I get is this -

```
<Instance_Updated>
  <Instance>
    <Field Name="INSTANCE_LABEL">00010541</Field>
    <Field Name="MAT_ID">TEST</Field>
    <Field Name="DEVICE_ID">TEST</Field>
  </Instance>
  <Item>
    <Field Name="MATERIAL_ID">TEST</Field>
    <Field Name="TITLE">TEST</Field>
    <Field Name="ON_AIR_DURATION">A</Field>
  </Item>
</Instance_Updated>
```

The InstanceUpdated class itself is:

```
    [XmlType("Instance_Updated"), Serializable]
    public class InstanceUpdated : SnellMessage
    {
        public InstanceUpdated()
        {
            InstanceFields = new List<Field>()
            {
                new Field() { Name = "INSTANCE_LABEL" },
                new Field() { Name = "MAT_ID" },
                new Field() { Name = "DEVICE_ID" }
            };

            ItemFields = new List<Field>()
            {
                new Field() { Name = "MATERIAL_ID" },
                new Field() { Name = "TITLE" },
                new Field() { Name = "ON_AIR_DURATION" }
            };
        }

        [XmlArray("Instance")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Field")]
        public List<Field> InstanceFields { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("Item")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Field")]
        public List<Field> ItemFields { get; set; }
   }

    [XmlType("Field"), Serializable]
    public class Field
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

When i try to parse the message -

```
InstanceUpdated instanceUpdatedMessage = SnellMessage.Deserialize<InstanceUpdated>(i_RootMessage.ToString());
```

In a 'Field' object I get NULL value instead of the string itself.

For example:
I assume the Value property of the Field 'INSTANCE_LABEL' should be '00010541' but inside i get a NULL value.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that the values of `Field.Value` are coming back null.  The problem is that you are allocating the `InstanceFields` and `ItemFields` lists in the *constructor* for `InstanceUpdated`, after which `XmlSerializer` **appends** the deserialized fields from the XML file.  If you re-serialize the XML, you will see each field has been duplicated:

```
  <Instance>
    <Field Name="INSTANCE_LABEL" />
    <Field Name="MAT_ID" />
    <Field Name="DEVICE_ID" />
    <Field Name="INSTANCE_LABEL">00010541</Field>
    <Field Name="MAT_ID">TEST</Field>
    <Field Name="DEVICE_ID">TEST</Field>
  </Instance>
```

Sample [repo fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h9e415).

For an explanation of why this happens, see [XML Deserialization of collection property with code defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27954653/3744182).

Your workarounds include:

- Move the collection initializations out of the constructor and into some factory.
- Serialize a surrogate array property.  Since arrays are read-only, the array must be set back once fully populated, e.g.:

  ```
  [XmlIgnore]
  public List<Field> InstanceFields { get; set; }

  [XmlArray("Instance")]
  [XmlArrayItem("Field")]
  public Field [] InstanceFieldsArray
  {
      get
      {
          if (InstanceFields == null)
              return null;
          return InstanceFields.ToArray();
      }
      set
      {
          (InstanceFields = InstanceFields ?? new List<Field>()).Clear();
          InstanceFields.AddRange(value ?? Enumerable.Empty<Field>());
      }
  }
  ```

  Sample [fixed fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hToEJC).

Comment: Thank you, I removed the constructor of InstanceUpdated and the XmlSerializer did add all the fields by itself.