# C# Xml Serializer deserializes list to count of 0 instead of null

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I am confused on how [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) works behind the scenes. I have a class that deserializes XML into an object. What I am seeing is for the following two elements that are NOT part of the Xml being deserialized.

```
[XmlRootAttribute("MyClass", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class MyClass
{
    private string comments;
    public string Comments
    {
        set { comments = value; }
        get { return comments; }
    }

    private System.Collections.Generic.List<string> tests = null;
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<string> Tests
    {
        get { return tests; }
        set { tests = value; }
    }
}
```

Let's take the following XML as an example:

```
<MyClass>
  <SomeNode>value</SomeNode>
</MyClass>
```

You notice that Tests and Comments are NOT part of the XML.

When this XML gets deserialized Comments is null(which is expected) and Tests is an empty list with a count of 0.

If someone could explain this to me it would be much appreciated.  What I would prefer is that if `<Tests>` is missing from the XML then the list should remain null, but if a (possibly empty) node `<Tests />` is present then the list should get allocated.

Comment: @gdir are you saying when you serialize this you get a null value for a list instead of empty list?

Comment: No what i am asking is that since tests is NOT part of the xml that when serialized it should be null instead of empty list. Does that make sense?

Comment: OP's question is about deserialization not serialization.  When the XML above is deserialize the `tests` collection is allocated even though `<Tests />` never appears in the XML.  (I can reproduce it, by the way.)

Comment: Edited to deserialize thanks

Comment: I don't know any place this behavior is documented.  When `<Tests>` is completely missing you don't want the list to be allocated.  What do you want when there is an empty `<Tests />` node?

Comment: To me it makes sense for the case of <Tests/> to be empty list. But if tests is not present it should be null.

Comment: Turns out it behaves as expected when using an array instead of a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are observing is that members referring to modifiable collections such as `List<T>` are automatically pre-allocated by `XmlSerializer` at the beginning of deserialization.  I am not aware of any place where this behavior is documented.  It may be related to the behavior described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27954653) to *[XML Deserialization of collection property with code defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27927496)*, which explains that, since `XmlSerializer` [supports adding to get-only and pre-allocated collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34247401/3744182), if a pre-allocated collection *contains default items* then the deserialized items will be appended to it - possibly duplicating the contents.  Microsoft may simply have chosen to pre-allocate **all** modifiable collections at the beginning of deserialization as the simplest way of implementing this.

The workaround from that answer, namely to use a surrogate array property, works here as well.  Since an array cannot be appended to, `XmlSerializer` must accumulate all the values and set them back when deserialization is finished.  But if the relevant tag is never encountered, `XmlSerializer` apparently does not begin accumulating values and so does not call the array setter.  This seems to prevent the default pre-allocation of collections that you don't want:

```
[XmlRootAttribute("MyClass", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class MyClass
{
    private string comments;
    public string Comments
    {
        set { comments = value; }
        get { return comments; }
    }

    private System.Collections.Generic.List<string> tests = null;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<string> Tests
    {
        get { return tests; }
        set { tests = value; }
    }

    [XmlArray("Tests")]
    public string[] TestsArray
    {
        get
        {
            return (Tests == null ? null : Tests.ToArray());
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                return;
            (Tests = Tests ?? new List<string>(value.Length)).AddRange(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7fzVdr) showing that `Tests` is allocated only when appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use the "magic" "Specified" suffix:

```
public bool TestsSpecified {get;set;}
```

If you have a serialized field/property XXX and a boolean property XXXSpecified, then the bool property is set according to whether or not the main field/property was set.

Answer (score 0):

We wound up here after a google search for the same issue.
What we ended up doing was checking for Count == 0, after deserialization, and manually setting the property to null;

```
...
var varMyDeserializedClass = MyXmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(myInput));
if (varMyDeserializedClass.ListProperty.Count == 0)
{
  varMyDeserializedClass.ListProperty = null;
}
...
```

It's a cheap workaround, but provides the expected result and is useful to avoid refactoring or redesign.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]` to the property, the List will be null after deserialization.

Comment: This does not work for me. Have you tried it or was it just an idea?

Comment: You're correct, I was on a wrong track /sorry