# JAXB Unmarshalling Issue (Getting empty list)

Tags: jaxb

I am trying to parse below XML document using JAXB api, where I want to parse each item in PROPERTYDATALIST which holds multiple PROPERTYDATA objects. During unmarshalling of the document I am getting an empty list. Any help on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FACILITY>
    <ARRANGEMENTACTIVITY>
        <ID>NEW</ID>
        <CUSTOMER>500000030</CUSTOMER>
        <CUSTOMERROLE>OWNER</CUSTOMERROLE>      
        <PROPERTYDATALIST>
            <PROPERTYDATA>
                <PROPERTY>FACOMMITMENT</PROPERTY>
                <AMOUNT>600000</AMOUNT>
                <TERM>5Y</TERM>
                <MATURITYDATE>20261001</MATURITYDATE>
            </PROPERTYDATA>
            <PROPERTYDATA>
                <PROPERTY>PRINCIPALINT</PROPERTY>
                <FIXEDRATE>3.5</FIXEDRATE>
            </PROPERTYDATA>         
        </PROPERTYDATALIST>
    </ARRANGEMENTACTIVITY>
</FACILITY>
```

Below are the classes I wrote to unmarshall the XML file

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "FACILITY")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Facility {
    @XmlElement(name = "ARRANGEMENTACTIVITY")
    private ArrangementActivity arrangementActivity;
    
}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id", "customer","propertyDataList", "application", "version", "operation"})
@Data
public class ArrangementActivity {

    @XmlElement(name = "APPLICATION")
    private String application;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "VERSION")
    private String version;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "OPERATION")
    private String operation;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "CUSTOMER")
    private String customer;    
    
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "PROPERTYDATALIST")
    @XmlElement(name = "PROPERTYDATALIST")
    private List<PropertyData> propertyDataList;    
}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@Data
@XmlType(propOrder = {"property", "amount", "term", "maturityDate", "fixedRate" })
public class PropertyData {
    
    @XmlElement(name = "PROPERTY")
    private String property;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "AMOUNT")
    private String amount;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "TERM")
    private String term;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "MATURITYDATE")
    private String maturityDate;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "FIXEDRATE")
    private String fixedRate;
        
}
```

```
public class JaxbExampleMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        String fileSourcePath = // file path";
        try {
            
            File file = new File( fileSourcePath);              
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file); 
                
            final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
            final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Facility.class).createUnmarshaller();
            final Facility facility = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, Facility.class).getValue();
            System.out.println(facility.toString());

            Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Facility.class).createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            marshaller.marshal(facility, System.out);
            
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

with above code I am getting all elements except for above PropertyDataList. Below is the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see few issues with your code:

1. You have added multiple root elements (ArrangementActivity,PropertyData) to your java classes. There should be only one root element (Facility).
2. You have added few properties in `proporder` you should include all of them unless any of them are marked as `transient`.
3. Your XML has the fields `capitalized` but your fields are in lowercase so it cannot assign the values directly during the `unmarshalling`. You can use the `@XmlElement` to assign what name it will have in XML.
4. (The one you asked for) You have to use the `@XmlElementWrapper` to your list along with `XmlElement`.

Note: I have used `Project Lombok Getter & Setter` so I do not have the `Getter/Setter` methods in each class

Following is the code which is unmarshalling and marshaling your XML:

Facility.class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "FACILITY")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Facility {

    @XmlElement(name = "ARRANGEMENTACTIVITY")
    private ArrangementActivity arrangementActivity;
}
```

ArrangementActivity.class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id", "customer","propertyDataList","application","version","operation"})
@Data
public class ArrangementActivity {

    @XmlElement(name = "APPLICATION")
    private String application;

    @XmlElement(name = "VERSION")
    private String version;

    @XmlElement(name = "OPERATION")
    private String operation;

    @XmlElement(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "CUSTOMER")
    private String customer;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "PROPERTYDATALIST")
    @XmlElement(name = "PROPERTYDATA")
    private List<PropertyData> propertyDataList;
}
```

PropertyData.class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@Data
@XmlType(propOrder = {"property", "amount", "term", "maturityDate", "fixedRate" })
public class PropertyData {

    @XmlElement(name = "PROPERTY")
    private String property;

    @XmlElement(name = "AMOUNT")
    private String amount;

    @XmlElement(name = "TERM")
    private String term;

    @XmlElement(name = "MATURITYDATE")
    private String maturityDate;

    @XmlElement(name = "FIXEDRATE")
    private String fixedRate;
}
```

JaxbExampleMain.class:

```
public class JaxbExampleMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        final InputStream inputStream = Unmarshalling.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("facility.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Facility.class).createUnmarshaller();
        final Facility facility = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, Facility.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(facility.toString());

        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Facility.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(facility, System.out);
    }
}
```

Following is the output you get:

```
Facility(arrangementActivity=ArrangementActivity(application=null, version=null, operation=null, id=NEW, customer=500000030, propertyDataList=[PropertyData(property=FACOMMITMENT, amount=600000, term=5Y, maturityDate=20261001, fixedRate=null), PropertyData(property=PRINCIPALINT, amount=null, term=null, maturityDate=null, fixedRate=3.5)]))
<FACILITY>
   <ARRANGEMENTACTIVITY>
      <ID>NEW</ID>
      <CUSTOMER>500000030</CUSTOMER>
      <PROPERTYDATALIST>
         <PROPERTYDATA>
            <PROPERTY>FACOMMITMENT</PROPERTY>
            <AMOUNT>600000</AMOUNT>
            <TERM>5Y</TERM>
            <MATURITYDATE>20261001</MATURITYDATE>
         </PROPERTYDATA>
         <PROPERTYDATA>
            <PROPERTY>PRINCIPALINT</PROPERTY>
            <FIXEDRATE>3.5</FIXEDRATE>
         </PROPERTYDATA>
      </PROPERTYDATALIST>
   </ARRANGEMENTACTIVITY>
</FACILITY>
```

Comment: I updated point 1 and 4 as mentioned in your answer in my code, but it's still bringing empty list `Facility [arrangementActivity=ArrangementActivity [id=NEW, customer=500000030, propertyDataList=[]]]`

Comment: I have provided you with the complete working code snippet. Please try this code it is working as expected for me. After that maybe try adding your code samples one by one to know what exactly could be wrong with your code. If nothing works then you can maybe update the question with the new code sample.

Comment: I have updated my question with new code changes, but still seeing empty list (propertyDataList)

Comment: You have added the same `name` for `@XmlElementWrapper` and `@XmlElement` for the `PROPERTYDATALIST`. It should be `@XmlElementWrapper(name = "PROPERTYDATALIST")` and `@XmlElement(name = "PROPERTYDATA")`. Please check my code again and make the modifications accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. After making above modifications, I can see the list getting populated with values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot 3, you should use Jakarta xml binding dependencies.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <!-- JAXB API only -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAXB RI, Jakarta XML Binding -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```